# ‘class octomap::ColorOcTree’ has no member named ‘genKey’ (hydro)

Tags: ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I have to make fuerte code runable under hydro. By compiling one package i get the following error:

```
‘class octomap::ColorOcTree’ has no member named ‘genKey’
```

I read in this log entry https://code.google.com/p/mrpt/source/browse/trunk/otherlibs/octomap/CHANGELOG.txt?r=3081, that genKey is deprecated. The author seems to use coordToKey instead. I tried that, but the problem is, that this function doesn't return a boolean value like genKey. But in the code this boolen is needed for an if clause. Does someone know, which function does the same like genKey and returns a boolean.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/172016/%E2%80%98class-octomap::coloroctree%E2%80%99-has-no-member-named-%E2%80%98genkey%E2%80%99-(hydro)/) by [mr42](https://answers.ros.org/users/18686/mr42/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-05-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please refer to the official API documentation of OctoMap online: http://octomap.github.io/octomap/doc/

If you need the bool return value there is a function `coordToKeyChecked` as replacement.

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2014-06-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1